# Invoke jQuery ajaxSuccess (or any global AJAX event) even if the local success (or any local AJAX event) throws an error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

It is not mentioned in the docs, but apparently if the local AJAX success handler throws an error, even the global ajaxSuccess handler is not invoked. Is there a way around this mechanism cause if you want to distribute a JS library or util function that does something on ajaxSuccess, you can't necessarily have control over the success handler and make sure it does not raise an exception.

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(ev, jqXHR, settings) {
  console.log('ajaxSuccess called!'); // does not get called
});

$.ajax({
  'url': '/',
  'type': 'GET',
  'success': function (response) {
    console.log('success called!');
    throw new Error();
  }
});
```

CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ldybr

Comment: Have you tried using `dataFilter` property? See [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/juGxk). But it fires before any local callbacks, so this maybe not the thing that you want to do.

Comment: @IlyaLuzyanin Excellent alternative! While that's certainly more than enough for my specific case, I'm still keeping the question open to see if there is a general way of making sure the global event handlers fire even if the local handlers error. Thanks!

Comment: you're welcome! I'd like to see the solution too, but something tells me that this is the way how it works - global handlers fire only after all local handlers and only in case there was no exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/) that partially explains the issue you're facing:

> **Events**
>   ...
>   **success** (Local Event)
>   This event is only called if the request was successful (no errors from the server, no errors with the data).
>   **ajaxSuccess** (Global Event)
>   This event is also only called if the request was successful.
>   **error** (Local Event)
>   This event is only called if an error occurred with the request (you can never have both an error and a success callback with a request).
>   **ajaxError** (Global Event)
>   This global event behaves the same as the local error event.

This is the normal flow of events, i.e. any global event is called *after* local. But in case any callback throws exception, no other callback is called, because jQuery internally doesn't wrap the callback in try-catch (you may do this locally in your callback though).

Another solution, as I've mentioned in comments, is dataFilter property of [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) options, which allows you to perform needed actions before any local callback (success or error) is called. Here is [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/juGxk) from my comments to the question, just in case:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  dataFilter: function(data, type) {
    console.log('dataFilter called!');
    return data;
  }
});
```